# How to send C# objects to PHP pages?

Tags: c#, php, .net, web-services

What is the best way to transfer an object from C# to PHP?

Lets say I have this:

```
class MyClass {
  public string name;
  public int id;
}
```

I then want to send it to a PHP page and receive it as an object (I have more complex datatypes in mind).

How can I do that, from the C# side and from the PHP side?

Comment: You'll need to find some way to serialize the object that works for you, common ways are to serialize to XML or JSON

Comment: @user1813579 As JG said, however, you probably would want to store the XML file onto a server and have the XML pull from it

Comment: I strongly recommend JSON as opposed to XML - it's lighter, and designed specifically for this kind of task. XML is defined to do more, and would be overkill for this scenario.

Comment: thanks! is json supported natively by C# and php? what are the best packages in php for that?

Comment: im sorry i moved this question here as it was closed! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14531719/c-sharp-client-php-web-server-couchbase-db-how-to-pass-data-between-them

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way is to serialise to and from a text based format, for example JSON. Both languages should have ready-made serializers. Or XML if you prefer that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use ["nusoap](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nusoap/)" on php side and xml serializers on C# side